# Vue3 Pouchdb example

Tags: vuejs3, pouchdb

I try to get Vue3 and Pouchdb working. There are many examples for Vue2 with pouchdb but there is simple no example for Vue3.

All my attempts to adapt some of the code for Vue2 did not lead to working code. Why is there nothing about Vue3 and pouchdb? What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

I also don't know.. but what I've noticed is the pouchdb- tools out there are all old and unmaintained.

I did find - https://dev.to/craftzdog/a-performant-way-to-use-pouchdb7-on-react-native-in-2022-24ej

I'm planning to fire up a vue app and see if following - https://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html works..

One thing I have noticed is that CouchDB/pouchDB is no longer the 'shiny thing' and so people are chasing the latest.. However, I got Pouchdb to load and create a DB.. will push a MWE later